# MS SQL retrieve related data from same table in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called mc.staff which in its simplest form is

---

id | name | supervisorId

---

I need a query which will pull out the id and name of a person, but also the id and name of their supervisor in one row. I have been told using some sort of self join to the table would work but I can't seem to figure out the logic behind it.
Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to use INNER JOIN here. INNER JOIN is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them, as long as there is a match in BOTH tables. The similarity that we will be using here is the supervisorId of mc.staff and the id of mc.staff.

Thus, the following query will return the results.

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.id, B.name
FROM mc.staff A
INNER JOIN mc.staff B ON A.supervisorId = B.id
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. Worked straight away! Thanks again